# Android - advice on writing my recursive method more efficiently for two independent animations

Tags: java, android, animation, recursion

I'm new to Java and Android programming and taking a course on this via Coursera. My app has two images that animate up and down. Right now, I've gotten as far as having both images animate together repeatedly. I got help and wrote a recursive method to have them animate repeatedly until a pleaseStop boolean flag is changed.

I would like them to move independently. **Rather than writing two stepRecursive methods, how can I write just one?**

Here's where I set up and run the animation.

```
 mHandler = new Handler(); // .os package class when importing
        mLeftfoot = findViewById(R.id.leftfoot);
        mRightfoot = findViewById(R.id.rightfoot);  
        mFootAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.foot); //this looks to the foot.xml file for the animations
        stepRecursive();
```

**Here's my recursive method. Notice mInterval. I would like mLeftfoot and mRightfoot to run at their own mInterval.**

```
private void stepRecursive() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLeftfoot.startAnimation(mFootAnim);
                mRightfoot.startAnimation(mFootAnim);
                if (!pleaseStop)
                    stepRecursive();
            }
        }, mInterval);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass one `boolean` variable via `stepRecursive()` method and decide which `View` has to be animated based on that `boolean` value...

```
private void stepRecursive(final boolean isLeftFoot,final int mInterval) {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isLeftFoot) {
                mLeftfoot.startAnimation(mFootAnim);
            } else {
                mRightfoot.startAnimation(mFootAnim);
            }
            if (!pleaseStop)
                stepRecursive(isLeftFoot,mInterval);
        }
    }, mInterval);
}
```

and when calling this method, pass appropriate interval based on the `boolean` value.

like

```
stepRecursive(true,intervalForLeft);
stepRecursive(false,intervalForRight);
```

Comment: Very close! Remember, I need mLeftfoot to run at a different mInterval as mRightfoot. It's not one OR the other. They are both animating, just at different intervals.

Comment: Don't I need two mIntervals? mLeftInterval and mRightInterval? Also, could you update the code with you answer? Thanks!!